# I keep getting a 'cannot find symbol' error in Java trying to implement a Stack as an array

Tags: java, arrays, stack

So for an assignment I need to implement a Stack using an array. I have all of the code figured out, but for some reason whenever I try to use my char array, Java says it can't find it. Here is my stack class.

```
public class Stack
{
    private int top;

    public Stack ()
    {
        char []charArray = new char [50];
        top = -1;
    }

    public void push(char c)
    {
        top++;
        charArray[top] = c;
    }

    public void pop()
    {
        top--;
    }

    public char top()
    {
        return charArray[top];
    }

    public void makeNull()
    {
        top=-1;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (top==-1);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why I'm having these errors? It doesn't like the lines in push and top where I reference charArray.

Comment: Off topic, but I see you don't have a `isFull` type of method, best to add resizability to your `charArray` to avoid a possible `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array variable `charArray` is declared as a local variable inside the constructor, and thus is not visible to the other methods.

You can declare it as a member field:

```
 private int top;
 private char[] charArray;

 public Stack ()
 {
    charArray = new char [50];
    top = -1;
 }
```